# Bind sass variable on vue props

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

i tried to create reusable component on vue js, i using sass variables for consistency color, size etc. And i have no idea to passing sass variable using props on vue js. if I use it directly in `<style>` like this, it works fine.

```
<template lang="pug">
  button.button-filled {{ title }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: { default: "", type: String }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="sass">
.button-filled
  background: $primary
  padding: $p-1 $p-4
  color: $white
  font-weight: 500
</style>
```

[image]

But if I use that variable in props like this, it doesn't work as it should

```
<template lang="pug">
  button.button-filled(
    :style="{ 'background': backgroundColor }"
  ) {{ title }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    backgroundColor: { default: "$bg-info", type: String },
    title: { default: "", type: String }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="sass">
.button-filled
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when you place the styles in the `style` tag the SASS can be compiled, but outside of it, it can't.

Perhaps using CSS Variables, instead of SASS, can help solve the problem.

Example:
`backgroundColor: { default: "var(--bg-info)", type: String },`